# Simulating a multistage Cockcroft-Walton circuit in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, high-voltage

I am trying to simulate a Cockcroft-Walton circuit in LTspice. I need an output of 15KV for an amplitude of 12V 50Hz AC supply. I got as expected 24V output after the first stage and cascading I am able to get higher voltages.

The problem came when I thought instead of copy pasting recursively I could make hierarchical schematic and repeat the block till I got 15KV. Using a single block alone I am able to make 24V but cascading two instead of 48V I am getting only 12V. I need a proof before I could proceed to PCB design. I have attached the corresponding waveforms and the schematics.

[image: two stage CW circuit]

[image: Basic CW circuit]

[image: CW using blocks]

[image: Basic CW circuit]

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: Sathya, you have everything you need there. Take a look at your first successful run (near 48 V). Looks okay. So the schematic is good. Then look at your little module there. Do you see a ground reference? Not so good. Go back to your first diagram. Compare. It should be clear what the problem is.

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for spotting this. I kind of overlooked.

Comment: @SathyaNarayan No problem. I've done worse! ;)

Comment: @SathyaNarayan I had assumed you were using a hierarchical circuit. (Like discussed [here](https://www.audio-perfection.com/spice-ltspice/hierarchical-blocks-in-ltspice/).) Were you instead duplicating labels?

Comment: @periblepsis Yes I used the hierarchical circuit, I was not aware same label gets connected. I have verified by removing labels and it works fine. Thanks again for pointing another mistake :-)

Comment: Aside from the issues with simulation, you'll never get 15kV from 12VAC with a C-W multiplier, but you'll find that out when the simulation works.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think all of us have been thinking about what Spehro just wrote. But one step at a time, eh?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks for the insight. I am pursing my degree and trying to recreate an existing negative ion generator 'jp-d1221'. Glad to hear if you have valuable suggestion.

Comment: The Chinese module will likely use a special high-frequency transformer designed for high voltage output (multi-segment bobbin for the secondary) connected in a very simple (deceptively simple!) BJT oscillator configuration and maybe a doubler on the output. Simulation of that kind of oscillator generally requires modeling the nonlinear characteristics of the transformer core.  If you want to use C-W at mains frequency, start with a much higher input voltage. But this is all another question for another time.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany will go through this further and pull seperate question when I am ready. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t reuse node names for nodes that are not the same point in a circuit. If you have two nodes with the same name such as **VOUT**, LTspice will think they are connected. It looks like this is what you have done in the third picture

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant to do. I removed the labels and it works as expected